# Ошибка PyQT5 при запуске программы!

Tags: python, pyqt5

давно борюсь с ошибкой PyQT5. Взял код с одного сайта, чтобы посмотреть пример работы с этим плагином, но когда запустил программу то без конца вылетает это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста!
Версия Python: 3.9
IDE: PyCharm

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115322/discussion-on-question-by-qu1ck-1337--pyqt5---).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена! Ошибка была в том, что путь до файла был написан с кирилицей(пример: c:\user\ **ЖОРА**\other), из за этого выходила ошибка! Ес -3 часа жизни, УХУ!